# history.pushState navigation - what about meta tags - separate template?

Tags: php, ajax, seo, meta-tags, pushstate

i have been building a jquery navigation based site without reloads ( using PHP and AJAX ) and have recently come across the problem of page "back", "forward", and "reload" features as well as SEO friendliness.

--**skip this section to get straight to question**--

[my site](http://kylepreuss.com) is currently (not using AJAX but ) loading a single index.php which has several "content" divs, one of which is visible (class="active") while the others are not displayed. When the user clicks a navigation link, a nice animation switches between content divs.

I have apache rewrites to map things like

`http://mysite.com/about`
to
`http://mysite.com/index.php?page=about`

where the "about" section would be the one thats displayed by default (while the other "content" divs are hidden). based on this parameter, i include the proper meta tags for the pages. my sitemap has mysite.com/about, mysite.com/blog so that they get indexed as nice separate pages.

However, I've recently decided to make this ajax-based since i plan to incorporate a lot more content and its stupid to load all content on one page.

Note: I'm also now implementing Smarty templates.

I decided to implement hash tags, but saw the inherent SEO problems, then i discovered hashbangs (wth?!) and then found the new HTML5 stuff with **history.pushState()** and **History.js** and have decided to use it.

**so here comes the main question**

if i have just one page which loads page templates in a content div with ajax, using history.pushState() to modify URL and using mod_rewrite and a PHP back-end that can serve a default content template in the case of a direct request like "mysite.com/about" (mysite.com/index.php?page=about) (for basic useabilty and SEO), i cannot also set meta content for direct requests unless i have two templates - a content template - and a meta template? is there another way around this?

are tags like `<title>` and `<meta name="description">` important enough to warrant having a template especially for them?

in summary, i want my nice mod_rewrite URLS to pull up on google with the correct title and meta description for a particular ajax-loaded page content template.

**EDIT**

i'm going for pretty much the same thing they have going on here at [hypem.com](http://hypem.com). they have an event listener which changes the `<title>` tag when new content is listed. they also serve the correct `<meta name="description">` tag, but only if it is a direct request to one of the main pages, like blogs - other pages, like http://hypem.com/blog/indie+today/10332, return the meta tag for the main blog page, and only when directly requested

Answer (score -1):

I would first build the site to work with all direct links and no ajax, and then add the ajax. However, only include the code that adds the ajax/history functionality if the page is being requested by a browser. If a web crawler hits your site, don't include the ajax/history functionality.